# error on LXD container while we install JUJU gui ver. 2.0

Tags: juju, lxc

lab:

nr. 1 Host with Ubuntu 16.04LTS - LXD & ZFS

nr. 2 - LXC Container (MAAS & JUJU)

I've already create a container for MAAS, and it's in running state

> **$: lxc list**
>
> +-------------+---------+--------------------+------+------------+-----------+
>
> |    NAME     |  STATE  |        IPV4        | IPV6 |    TYPE    |
> SNAPSHOTS |
>
> +-------------+---------+--------------------+------+------------+-----------+
>
> | xenial-maas | RUNNING | 10.20.40.29 (eth0) |      | PERSISTENT | 0

I'd like also create an LXD Xenial controller for JUJU using the following command

**$: juju bootstrap lxd xenial-juju --debug**

after having started the container

> **$: lxc list**
>
> +---------------+---------+--------------------+------+------------+-----------+
>
> | NAME | STATE | IPV4 | IPV6 | TYPE | SNAPSHOTS |
>
> +---------------+---------+--------------------+------+------------+-----------+
>
> | juju-6f0b4e-0 | RUNNING | 10.20.40.57 (eth0) | | PERSISTENT | 0 |
>
> +---------------+---------+--------------------+------+------------+-----------+
>
> | xenial-maas | RUNNING | 10.20.40.29 (eth0) | | PERSISTENT | 0 |
>
> +---------------+---------+--------------------+------+------------+-------
> ----+

it gives me the following error:

> 12:37:11 ERROR cmd supercommand.go:458 failed to bootstrap model:
> subprocess encountered error code 1

here the debug file https://paste.ubuntu.com/23450682/

while without --debug the error on the screen is the following

> 2016-11-09 10:16:12 ERROR cmd supercommand.go:458 new environ:
> creating LXD client: Get https://10.20.40.254:8443/1.0: Unable to
> connect to: 10.20.40.254:8443 ERROR failed to bootstrap model:
> subprocess encountered error code 1

after that the container is removed

**$: lxc list**

+-------------+---------+--------------------+------+------------+-----------+

|    NAME     |  STATE  |        IPV4        | IPV6 |    TYPE    |
SNAPSHOTS |

+-------------+---------+--------------------+------+------------+-----------+

| xenial-maas | RUNNING | 10.20.40.29 (eth0) |      | PERSISTENT | 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug :

https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju/+bug/1633788

Same problem for me . 
JUJU take the wrong IP address for LXD node

Where is what I did to be able to juju bootloade.

When the container is RUNNING you can go inside the container and then do this :

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d ${WRONG_IP} -p tcp --dport 8443 -j DNAT --to-destination ${GOOD_IP}:8443
```